# How to draw charts using c#?

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, winforms, charts

I have to draw a bar chart using c#. First I have tried using vb.net using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace.code here below

```
    Dim strConn As  string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=demo;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=root;";
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)

    Dim sqlProducts As String = "SELECT Top 8 ProductName, UnitsInStock FROM Products"
    Dim da As New MYSqlDataAdapter(sqlProducts, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "Products")

    Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
    Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
    Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()
    Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
    Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

    ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
    Legend1.Name = "Legend1"
    Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)
    Chart1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
    Chart1.Name = "Chart1"
    Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
    Series1.Legend = "Legend1"
    Series1.Name = "Series1"
    Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
    Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 400)
    Chart1.TabIndex = 0
    Chart1.Text = "Chart1"

    Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "date"
    Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "temperature"

    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("flowchart")
```

It was working perfectly same i have tried using c#

```
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=demo;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=root;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        con.Open();
        string s = "select date,temperature from flowchart";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "flowchart");

        ChartArea chartarea1 = new ChartArea();
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        Chart c1 = new Chart();
        Series series = new Series();
        Controls.Add(c1);

        chartarea1.Name = "ChartArea";
        c1.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea1);
        legend.Name = "Legend";
        c1.Legends.Add(legend);
        c1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        series.Name = "Series";
        c1.Series.Add(series);
        c1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 400);
        c1.TabIndex = 0;
        c1.Text = "Chart1";

        c1.Series("Series").XValueMember = "date";
        c1.Series("Series").YValueMembers = "temperature";
        c1.DataSource = ds.Tables("flowchart");
```

getting error in last three lines.I don't know it was correct method or not.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: for last three lines getting error like Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Series' cannot be used like a method.'

Comment: Use `[...]` instead of `(...)` on those 3 lines.

Comment: working fine Lasse V.Karlsen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C# when you supplying parameter in list/collection or array then it should be written in square bracket `[]`. only methods or function's parameter can have round bracket `()`.   `

it should be written like this

```
c1.Series["Series"].XValueMember = "date";`
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [`Chart.Series`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.series%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property and it returns [`SeriesCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to use [`Series.XValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.xvaluemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Series.YValueMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.yvaluemembers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties with it, you need to use indexers ([`ChartNamedElementCollection<T>.Item Property (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) with it like;

```
c1.Series["Series"].XValueMember = "date";
c1.Series["Series"].YValueMembers = "temperature";
```